# How SUPERUSER_ID works with access groups

Tags: odoo-14, access-rights, superuser

I would like to ask, what is the point of checking whether superuser has specific access groups in Odoo 14?
My understanding was, that superuser has/ignores all access groups.
*stock/models/res_config_settings.py*

```
    def set_values(self):
    ...
    was_operations_showed = self.env['stock.picking.type'].with_user(SUPERUSER_ID)._default_show_operations()
    res = super(ResConfigSettings, self).set_values()
    ...    
    return res
```

*addons/stock/models/stock_picking.py*

```
def _default_show_operations(self):
    return self.user_has_groups('stock.group_production_lot,'
                                'stock.group_stock_multi_locations,'
                                'stock.group_tracking_lot')
```

Answer (score 1):

`SUPERUSER_ID` matches OdooBot user. Using `with_user(SUPERUSER_ID)` is equal to `sudo()`

`_default_show_operations` method checks if user in context has rights because it is not obvious method is going to be called from OdooBot. It may be called from an user too in a different piece of code.

For sure `was_operations_showed` could just be set to `True` in this case to optimize code, but this wouldn't be passively in case `_default_show_operations` gets a logic refactoring (for example enforcing the check with further conditions not related to user permissions)